# Async/Await - Typescript and ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, async-await

I am experiencing with typescript's async/await in express. I have the following code snippet which doesn't product any outcome, it just waits as if the promise is never finished. Any ideas how to make it work.

```
  ..
  router.get('/test', this.test);
  ..

  private async test(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const result = await this.test2();
    res.json(result);
  }

  private async test2() {
    return await this.test3();
  }

  private test3() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve({ "working": true }) });
  }
```

**update:**

If I change the first line with the line below, it works. Any ideas why ?

```
router.get('/test', (req,res)=>this.test(req,res));
```

**update2 (fixed) - based on @smnbbrv answer below**

```
 private test = async(req: Request, res: Response)=> {
    const result = await this.test2();
    res.json(result);
  }

  private test2 = async ()=> {
    return await this.test3();
  }

  private test3 = async()=> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve({ "working": true }) });
  }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. I have tried running given snippet (with removed `res.json(result);`) and call to `test` function is successfully awaited and resolved. You problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your 'this' is lost after you pass it like that

```
router.get('/test', this.test);
```

If you simply preserve the `this` value by

```
router.get('/test', this.test.bind(this));
```

this should work exactly in the way you mentioned in update

```
router.get('/test', (req,res)=>this.test(req,res));
```